# SEGFAULT after inspecting variable with GDB on QtCreator

Tags: c++, gdb, qt-creator

I have the following situation: My program runs fine, does all I want it to do,  tests pass and Valgrind says it's all right. The only issue is the fact that if I pause execution at some point and try to inspect the state of some objects in the debug view of QtCreator (using GDB) some variables become `<not-accessible>` and, on resuming execution it reaches a segmentation fault.

To be a little more specific, the program is single threaded and this happens while following the pointers in a tree structure. The structure seems to be fine by the output of the tests.

Does anyone know about a possible cause? Maybe I have messed up with the stack in a way that luckily doesn't affect the tests or it may be just an IDE or debugger issue that should not care about? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I too found GDB (or perhaps its integration with Qt Creator) unreliable (buggy). At times, it would hang for several minutes and sometimes I needed to restart Qt. Not sure if it's a Qt or GDB issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know about a possible cause?

Do you have multiple threads in your program?

When a program behaves differently depending on whether some GDB breakpoints are present or not, in 99.99% of the cases the program has a data race, and mere fact of stopping it at "inopportune" time exposes that fact.

On Linux, you could use [Thread Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual) to check for data races.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of this sort of "heisenbug". The problem is that it is a single thread app.